# Is it safe to share layout instance among different controls

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a class which creates several controls but the class itself is not a composite or widget. The controls all have the layout as `new GridLayout(1, false)`. I am not sure whether I can define a class level `GridLayout` variable, and use it for all the controls? Here is the code example

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite comp1 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    comp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false);

    Composite comp2 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    comp2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false);

    // ... other stuff   
}
```

As you see here I created three identical `GridLayout` instances. Can I use one class level insance for all these controls? Any security issue or performance drawback?

Comment: By the way I usually re-use GridLayout and some other resources in my code and I've encountered no issues so far. But do not expect that making a change to the shared resource will change all Control/Widgets who received it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT doesn't really say if it is safe to reuse layout objects so you should assume that it is not safe.

From the look of the code `GridLayout` might be reusable but there is very little cost in using a new layout for each `Composite` so I have not tried this.

Alternatively you can use `GridLayoutFactory` to define a standard layout that you can apply to multiple composites:

```java
GridLayoutFactory factory = GridLayoutFactory.swtDefaults();

factory.applyTo(comp1);

factory.applyTo(comp2);
```

It is definitely **not** safe to reuse `GridData`, there must be a separate `GridData` object for each control.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But I take it it's safe to throw away the Layout reference after using it and using the same variable for something else, considering that the reference is thrown away in OP's `setLayout (new ...)` anyway, right? In my project I've got n (usually between 20 and 50, sometimes more) Composite objects with the same Layout (RowLayout, vertical, same spacing etc., just the number of children vary). To set them up I'm thinking of using just one Layout variable and set it up the same way for each Composite inside the loop that sets up those Composite-s.

Comment: @Heimdall Yes, that is OK. But these days I would use the JFace `GridLayoutFactory` and `GridDataFactory` if you can as they have a better interface.